# how do i create a grid of cards with angular material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to create a grid of three cards per row using ng-repeat. I have a normal array of javascript objects attached to the scope. The code below will create a fresh row for every card.

```
<div layout="row" ng-repeat='post in posts' layout-fill="" layout-align="">
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <h2 class="md-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
    <p>
      {{post.summary}}
    </p>
  </md-card-content>
  <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <md-button>View More</md-button>
  </div>
</md-card>
<br>
```

[image]

How can I iterate over my array and display the cards in rows of three? I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137496/angular-js-ng-repeat-for-creating-grid) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137496/angular-js-ng-repeat-for-creating-grid) but I do not see how they apply to [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/)

Comment: can you provide a codepen or fiddle for above?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have created something similar to what you may want. The `md-card` is wrapped within a `div` having `layout-wrap`. The divs are dynamically generated after reading.

Here is the code :

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <md-card style="width: 350px;" ng-repeat="user in users">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="md-card-image" alt="user avatar">
      <md-card-content>
        <h2>{{user}}</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
      </md-card-content>
      <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Save</md-button>
        <md-button>View</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

The cards width can be adjusted with inline styling, hope it helps.

Comment: this is ok, but I think it'd be even better if the wrapper div was defined with `flex` so that each `md-card` could inherit and define a responsive value `flex="33"` instead of binding a fixed width in the card

Comment: @gru Can you give the example? This sounds great but I can't create your solution in practice.

Comment: hey @gru thank you for your example, but it is not responsive - in very small witdth is broken. Is it possible to declare some attribute where I set the definition of count of cards in view for different width?

Comment: @Jenan in that case you should just use the normal breakpoint notation as described in [angular material layout docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) e.g. you'd have flex-sm, flex-md, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I just needed this; here's a more comprehensive solution, only using the layout features, for 3 columns:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <div flex="33" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
        <md-card>
            // ...
        </md-card>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

The card [must be wrapped](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/247) inside a correctly-sized div to keep the margins under control and avoid overflow.

Comment: `layout-wrap` is what solved my issue, flex wasn't working properly. I still can't understand why it is needed, I'm gonna read a bit more about how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To be compling to material/angular, you must use flex attr to md-card.
Flex attr will give you a proportional width about its parent.

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <md-card flex="40" flex-sm="80" ng-repeat="user in users">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="md-card-image" alt="user avatar">
      <md-card-content>
        <h2>{{user}}</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
      </md-card-content>
      <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Save</md-button>
        <md-button>View</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

In this example, you will have two cards (40% each) and when the screen resizes to -sm, the cards will be at 80%.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class="grid-container"` for this.
As an example a code snippet like this,

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px">
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
            <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8 card-prop"> CARD 1
            </mat-card>  
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="2">
            <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8 card-prop"> CARD 2
            </mat-card>  
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
            <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8 card-prop"> CARD 3
            </mat-card>  
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Will produce an output similar to this.

[image]